# Loading android google maps faster in emulator than in phone

Tags: android, google-maps, android-asynctask, android-emulator, geojson

I am loading geojson file in Google maps. Since the file is large, I am dividing the file into small chunks and trying to load them using parallel processing.

```
for (int i = 1; i < 3; i++) {
    new MyAsyncTask().executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR,i);
}
```

Async Task:

```
public class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask <Integer, Void, GeoJsonLayer> {

  @Override
  protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
  }

  @Override
  protected GeoJsonLayer doInBackground(Integer... integers) {
    int i = integers[0];
    try {
      GeoJsonLayer layer = null;
      switch (i) {
        case 1:
          layer = new GeoJsonLayer(mMap, R.raw.small_1, getApplicationContext());
          break;
        case 2:
          layer = new GeoJsonLayer(mMap, R.raw.small_2, getApplicationContext());
          break;
        //other cases
        }
        return layer;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    }
  }

  @Override
  protected void onPostExecute(GeoJsonLayer layer) {
    super.onPostExecute(layer);
    layer.addLayerToMap();
  }
}
```

I have run it in Emulator (Android 6.0, API 23) as well as in a phone (Samsung GT N7100, Andriod 4.4.2, API 19). The loading of map and showing the layers over it completes instantly in emulator while it takes some time (around 20 seconds) in my phone. Number of cores in emulator is 2 while in phone its 4.

```
 Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
```

Whats the reason for this? Isnt the phone supposed to be faster than emulator? I have also enabled the hardware acceleration option in manifest file. Is there any options that can be used for efficient loading in phones?

**Details of my emulator are as follows**

Name: Nexus_6P_API_23

CPU/ABI: Google APIs Intel Atom (x86)

Path: C:\Users\seasonal.android\avd\Nexus_6P_API_23.avd

Target: google_apis [Google APIs] (API level 23)

Skin: 1440x2560

SD Card: C:\Users\seasonal.android\avd\Nexus_6P_API_23.avd\sdcard.img

hw.dPad: no

runtime.network.speed: full

hw.accelerometer: yes

hw.device.name: Nexus 6P

vm.heapSize: 64

skin.dynamic: yes

hw.device.manufacturer: Google

hw.gps: yes

hw.initialOrientation: Portrait

skin.path.backup: _no_skin

image.androidVersion.api: 23

hw.audioInput: yes

image.sysdir.1: system-images\android-23\google_apis\x86\

tag.id: google_apis

showDeviceFrame: no

hw.camera.back: none

hw.mainKeys: no

AvdId: Nexus_6P_API_23

hw.camera.front: none

hw.lcd.density: 560

avd.ini.displayname: Nexus 6P API 23

hw.gpu.mode: auto

hw.device.hash2: MD5:9b564b60b1aebee32c73ded9daa1e620

hw.ramSize: 768

hw.trackBall: no

hw.battery: yes

hw.sdCard: yes

tag.display: Google APIs

runtime.network.latency: none

hw.keyboard: yes

hw.sensors.proximity: yes

disk.dataPartition.size: 800M

hw.sensors.orientation: yes

avd.ini.encoding: UTF-8

hw.gpu.enabled: yes